# how can I create a span element in form class in symfony 1.4

Tags: symfony-1.4, symfony-forms, form-fields

Is there any way to add custom form-field element in the form class?

i.e.

I want to add a span element just after the email element in the UsersForm class. Here is the code

```
class UsersForm extends BaseUsersForm
{

   public function configure()
   {
      unset($this['created'], $this['updated']);

      $this->widgetSchema['name'] = new sfWidgetFormInput();
      $this->widgetSchema['email'] = new sfWidgetFormInput();

      <!-- code for the span element here -->

      $this->widgetSchema['password'] = new sfWidgetFormInputPassword();
      $this->widgetSchema['retypepassword'] = new sfWidgetFormInputPassword(array(
        'label' => 'Retype Password'
      ));
   }
 }
```

What should be the code/method for adding span element exactly below the email 'form-field'?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This a ugly way, try to avoid this kind of hack :

```
$this->widgetSchema['password'] = new sfWidgetFormInputPassword(array('label'=>'<span></span>password'));
```

Comment: yeah, you are right. Isn't there a neat way of doing such things. Now where shall I show the response text if I cannot draw a element other than a model column.?

Comment: You can add a class to widget, and then, add a span with javascript. Or, you have to write all $form->render('field') and put a span element manually.